# material top tab bar force tab label only in one line

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

snack https://snack.expo.dev/@bryanltobing/juicy-pizza

I want to force the tab label to not wrap into the next line and force it into one line only

[image: Content]

but i couldn't achieve it

i have tried to add `tabBarLabelStyle` width to 100%
but it messes up the label wrapper

```
options={{
  tabBarLabel: "Internet Banking & Mobile Banking",
  tabBarLabelStyle: {
    width: "100%",
  },
}}
```

[image: Content]

```
tabBarLabelStyle: {
  // width: "100%",
+  flex-wrap: "nowrap",
},
```

`flex-wrap: nowrap` doesn't work as well

am i missing something? how can i achieve this.

Expected result is to have the label only in one line. and the container will be dynamically adjusted based on the label size

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to add an height to the label style.

```
tabBarLabelStyle: {
  "width":"100%",
  "height":"50%",
  "textAlign": "auto" // Optional
}
```

The height at 50% will place the label in the center, you can play with its value if you want your label higher up or lower down.